# Remove box in MS word Document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am working on a document on Word 2010 for a client and it was sent over formatted in such a way that all the pages have a box around them. I would like to remove this box but cannot figure out what exactly it is to remove it. The document I am working on is just shy of 100 pages so I cannot simply retype and format the whole thing.

I have created an example document which contain the same problem :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KXwQhH5kwQQTJVT1Yya18yb3c/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily remove it in "Design" section "Page Borders option" :
[image]

Source : [MS Word Help Center](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-change-or-delete-borders-from-documents-or-pictures-70e0af47-31c7-47ae-89f3-9ec587f1e49f)